Existence of Fokker-Planck equation under Cauchy boundary condition.
A 1D Fokker-Planck equation within a constrain region is uniquely characterized by three functions and a boundary conditon:

A drifting term $\mu(x,t)$.
A diffusion term $\sigma(x,t)$.
An initial distribution $p(x,0)$.
A Dirichlet/Neumann/Mixed boundary condition.

There's also a Cauchy boundary condition as specifying both the Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions, but they may conflict with each other and make the equation unsolvable. I'm wondering if it's possible to reverse the process to find a Fokker-Planck equation with solution satisfying any given cauchy boundary condition. For example, the following problem is of great interest:
If $p(x,t)$ satisfies
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(x,t)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[-\mu(x,t)p(x,t)]+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}[\frac{\sigma^2(x,t)}{2}p(x,t)],\\
p(a,t)=p_l(t),p(b,t)=p_r(t),\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}p(a,t)=p_a(t),\frac{\partial}{\partial x}p(b,t)=p_b(t),
$$
given any $p_l(t),p_r(t),p_a(t)$ and $p_b(t)$, is there a combination of $\mu(x,t)$, $\sigma(x,t)$ and $p(x,0)$ that satisfies the two boundary conditions and if there is, is the combination unique?
Note: the requirements may be relaxed like $0=p_l(t)=p_r(t)$ or $p(x,0)$ is given, in which case the problem can be viewed as whether it's possible to recover the Continuous-Time-Continuous-State Markov Process from the embedded Continuous-Time Markov Process with some chosen states.

Choose any function $p(x,t)$ that satisfies the boundary conditions at $a$ and $b$. Substitute into the FPE: $t$ now appears as a parameter so what remains is an ODE for the functions $\mu(x)$ and $\sigma(x)$. Fix one of these functions, then you have a linear non-homogeneous ODE for the other. This establishes a sufficient condition for your claim (ie. if the resulting equation has solutions), as well as the non-uniqueness

@Sal Many thanks. Found that even for 1st order ODE the claim is not true. The boundary conditions are still too weak to identify a unique function.
